# Doubt about a proof in Artin's book of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the affine morphisms' section of Michael Artin's book of Algebraic Geometry ([Algebraic Geometry: Notes on a Course](https://www.amazon.sg/Algebraic-Geometry-Course-Michael-Artin/dp/1470471116)), and I don't understand the red highlighted part of the following proof:

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tajCH.png)

Why does he use the fact that $f$ is in the localization $A_{s_i}$ to see that there is some power of $s_i$ that multiplied by $f$ lies in $A$, when he already has that $s_if = a_i$, and $a_i$ is in $A$?

Is there any detail that I'm missing?

**Notation:** He defines a rational function as an element of the field of fractions of $A$.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Yeah, you can assume the $n_i$'s to be $1$, because the localisations $X_s$ and $X_{s^n}$ are the same, just as the algebraic localisations $A_s$ and $A_{s^n}$. Tbh, that proof looks like a mess. First $f = a_i / s_i$, then $f = b_i / s_i^n$, and later on there appear different $a_i$'s to write $1 = \sum s_i^n a_i$. It looks a bit like the author had an idea to simplify his proof (omitting the $n_i$'s), but didn't really go through with it...